# When to use previous/next vs. back/forward? (and what about back/next?)

Tags: navigation

Is there any standard recommendation on when to use previous/next vs. back/forward? Or is there any reason not to pair back with next?

To me, previous/next make sense to use as a pair when navigating a linear sequence, such as flipping through the pages of a book, while back/forward should be used when navigating an environment that doesn't have a logical linear sequence, such as a web browser.

That said, I'm tempted to use back/next as a pair simply because of the fact that they are more concise words and have a symmetry in their number of characters.

Thoughts? Recommendations? Any empirical evidence on this subject?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You move **back** and **forward** in history.
You move to the **previous** and **next** element in a chain.

So *back* and *forward* are more specific than *previous* and *next*, i.e. the latter are always ok, the first only if the user has been there before (as Michael Histen already said).

Within these rules, *back* / *next* is a correct pair if you always start at the first element.

(You could switch between *forward* and *next* in this scenario, but there's no point to it, and it would likely confuse the user.)

Comment: these terms are lexical paired as directions of travel along a given dimension; doing mixing and match between dimensions is ill advised as it induces cognitive dissonance which reduces comprehension.

Comment: @ Dan D.: I don't see a problem with that, OTOH I'm not a native speaker, so I won't ague against that.

Answer (score 1):

I think the whole answer lies in what users expect!

- previous/next are the most obvious in many cases, because you see them almost everywhere (for example in case of forms, list of pages, Google, etc) - here's an article on how to use previous/next in case of forms http://www.uie.com/articles/previous_next_luke/
- can't think of any online situation when I saw back/forward
- but would never use the combination of it

Unfortunately I couldn't find any empirical evidence

Comment: I'm glad to get some agreement about the fact that these terms need to work as a pair. IOW, back/next doesn't really make sense. (..and thanks for the article link)

Answer (score 1):

In the browser interface, "Back" means "go to the last page I was on" -- it indicates returning to a place **you've been to before**. If you are using "back" to refer to older or previous content in a linear sequence that the user **may not have seen**, you are potentially creating confusion.